# Optimising multiple streams to single loop

Tags: java, loops, optimization, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to find the best way to optimise the converters below to follow the flow I call 'convertAndGroupForUpdate' first which triggers the conversions and relevant mappings.

Any help to optimise this code would be massively appreciated.

```
public List<GroupedOrderActionUpdateEntity> convertAndGroupForUpdate(List<SimpleRatifiableAction> actions) {
    List<GroupedOrderActionUpdateEntity> groupedActions = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<String, List<SimpleRatifiableAction>> groupSimple = actions.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getOrderNumber() + x.getActionType()));

    groupSimple.entrySet().stream()
            .map(x -> convertToUpdateGroup(x.getValue()))
            .forEachOrdered(groupedActions::add);

    return groupedActions;
}

public GroupedOrderActionUpdateEntity convertToUpdateGroup(List<SimpleRatifiableAction> actions) {
    List<OrderActionUpdateEntity> actionList = actions.stream().map(x -> convertToUpdateEntity(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new GroupedOrderActionUpdateEntity(
            actions.get(0).getOrderNumber(),
            OrderActionType.valueOf(actions.get(0).getActionType()),
            actions.get(0).getSource(),
            12345,
            actions.stream().map(SimpleRatifiableAction::getNote)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "Group Order Note: ", ".")),
            actionList);
}

public OrderActionUpdateEntity convertToUpdateEntity(SimpleRatifiableAction action) {
    return new OrderActionUpdateEntity(action.getId(), OrderActionState.valueOf(action.getState()));
}
```

Comment: you are better off on [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t elide a grouping operation, but you don’t need to store the intermediate result in a local variable.

Further, you should not add to a list manually, when you can `collect` to a `List`. Just do it like you did in the other method.

Also, creating a grouping key via string concatenation is tempting, but very dangerous, depending on the contents of the properties, the resulting strings may clash. And string concatenation is rather expensive. Just create a list of the property values, as long as you don’t modify it, it provides the right equality semantics and hash code implementation.

If you want to process the values of a map only, don’t call `entrySet()`, to map each entry via `getValue()`. Just use `values()` in the first place.

```
public List<GroupedOrderActionUpdateEntity> convertAndGroupForUpdate(
                                            List<SimpleRatifiableAction> actions) {
    return actions.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy( // use List.of(…, …) in Java 9 or newer
               x -> Arrays.asList(x.getOrderNumber(), x.getActionType())))
      .values().stream()
      .map(x -> convertToUpdateGroup(x))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Since `convertToUpdateGroup` is processing the list of actions of each group multiple times, there is not much that can be simplified and I wouldn’t inline it either. If there was only one operation, e.g. joining them to a string, you could do that right in the `groupingBy` operation, but there is no simply way to collect to multiple results.